# What can I substitute fennel pollen with?

Tags: substitutions, spices

In this simple [spaghetti](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/07/spaghetti-olive-oil-fennel-pollen-orange-garlic-mint-recipe.html) recipe, fennel pollen is used. From googling it, it sounds like MSG :). I'd rather not buy it since it's so expensive, so is there any way to substitute this stuff in the recipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try ground fennel seed, or even anise, but they will not have quite the same quality.  You would certainly have to increase the quantity.

In situations like this, I have to point out:  it does not make sense to make a dish where you are forced to substitute for the ingredient which gives the dish its identity.  Instead, make something where  you *can* employ the star ingredient.

Comment: Amen to the second paragraph... if I'm looking at recipes for veal parmigiana, and then realize I don't have/can't get any cheese, then I look for other recipes, not substitutions.